# Boost interprocess: How to start a new process?

Tags: c++, boost, cross-platform, ipc, boost-interprocess

I wonder if it is possible to start a new process with Boost.Interprocess in a crossplatform manner? Also I wonder if it is possible to start processes like `echo`?

Comment: Boost.Interprocess is more about interprocess communication than anything else afaik, so I don't think you'll have luck with that. Maybe try asio?

Answer (score 0):

The interprocess module doesn't have any functions pertaining to actually creating new processes.

have a look at the `system()` C function.